# Http post request for store token in database

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing push notifications in wordpress and everything works for me except store the tokens in the database.

I have the following function in AppDelegate.swift

```
// send token

func SendToken(_ token: String)
{
    //info device

    // append parameter to oneDictionary
    let tokenString = ["token": token] as [String: Any]


    // create the request

    let stringUrl = "http://example.com/wp/wp-json/apnwp/register?os_type=ios&user_email_id=pushx@40test.com&device_token=\(token)"

    let stringUrlEncoded = stringUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    let myUrl = URL(string: stringUrlEncoded!)



    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)


    // set the method as POST

     request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // append the paramter to body

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tokenString, options: [])

    // create the session
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("There was error during datatask session")
            print(error!)
        } else {
            do {
                guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else { return }
                //print(json as Any)

                guard let errors = json?["errors"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }


                if errors.count > 0 {
                    // show error
                    print("There is an error during parse JSON datatask")
                    return
                } else {
                    // show confirmation
                    print("datatask with JSON format performed successfully")
                }
            }
        }
        print(request)
    }).resume()
}
//end send token
```

The plugin documentation that I'm using says the following:

```
URL structure:

http://yourwordpresssite/wp-json/apnwp/register

Method:  GET

Parameters:
device_token (string): token given by APNs or FCM identifying the device, often called device ID.
os_type (string): operating system. It must be ios or android (case sensitive).
user_email_id (string, optional): the user email address which is login from your mobile app.

Examples:

http://yourwordpresssite/wp-json/apnwp/register?os_type=android&user_email_id=androidmobile@40test.com&device_token=1234567890
```

In AppDelegate.swift I call the function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {

        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])

    }
    print("New token is: \(token)")

    SendToken(token)

}
```

But it does not work to save the data in the database, but if I put the URL (`//yourwordpresssite/wp-json/apnwp/register?os_type=android&user_email_id=iosdmobile@40test.com&device_token=1234567890`) in the browser if it is stored in the database.

I would appreciate any help, what may be happening.

Comment: According to the documentation, it's a GET method, not a POST, and the token is in the URL, not in the Body.

Comment: Thanks to the information, every day you learn something new from this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to the **plugin documentation**, I found some concern in your code as:

**1. Method:  GET**

Your http method is GET, not POST

**2. httpBody as ["token": token]**

You are already appending token in the end of `urlRequest` as `?os_type=ios&user_email_id=pushx@40test.com&device_token=\(token)`.

Even GET requests are been called with `request.httpBody = nil`, all your parameters should be appended in `urlRequest`.

**3. Decode JSON object with `[ ]` rather `.allowFragments`**

I am not sure about this, but if you are not able to parse the data, you should use `[]` rather `.allowFragments`

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }
```

> Try updating your code as:

```
func SendToken(_ token: String) {
    // Create reuest
    let stringUrl = "http://example.com/wp/wp-json/apnwp/register?os_type=ios&user_email_id=pushx@40test.com&device_token=\(token)"
    let stringUrlEncoded = stringUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    let myUrl = URL(string: stringUrlEncoded!)
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)

    // set the method as GET
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    // append the paramter to body
    request.httpBody = nil

    // create the session
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("There was error during datatask session")
            print(error!)
        } else {
            do {
                guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }

                guard let errors = json?["errors"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

                if errors.count > 0 {
                    // show error
                    print("There is an error during parse JSON datatask")
                    return
                } else {
                    // show confirmation
                    print("datatask with JSON format performed successfully")
                }
            }
        }
        print(request)
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your help, it worked for me with `.allowFragments -> []`

Comment: @AlbertB, Welcome :)